# How do I save files to a user accessible location?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air

I am writing an application that can import and export data and I need the path to this data to be accessible to the user, but not on the SDcard. I would prefer to put it somewhere alongside the Downloads folder, or somewhere visible to a file explorer without root permissions. I do NOT want to save data to /data/data, but I would like to save it somewhere in /storage/emulated/0/. I don't know how to specify this location in a way that would support all android devices.

I have looked at many threads that are similar but not exactly what I want. Saving to the SDcard is not desirable since not everyone has external storage, but I also don't want to save to File.applicationDirectory or File.applicationStorageDirectory because the User is unable to view these locations.

Comment: `FileReference.save()`, also there should be a dialogue asking where to save the file. Not sure about the downloads folder, but there might be an envvar with exact path to downloads or parent folder, check if there's any.

Comment: @Vesper This won't work on Android because Android doesn't support browse-file-to-save-to dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to not only my own question, but several more I had on the way. In order to create files on android, you must first use File.requestPermission() to ask the user for STORAGE permissions. Next, I encountered a problem with accessing /storage/emulated/0, which is what File.userDirectory and File.documentsDirectory point to. What I found was that this location is now protected in android 6 (marshmallow) and up. (Courtesy of: https://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-s8-and-s8-plus/802115-why-storage-emulated-0-empty.html) Instead of using that path, I instead used /sdcard as suggested in that link. The name of this directory is misleading, but after reading http://www.stevesandroidguide.com/android-files/ I found out that sdcard-ext is the literal sdcard, and sdcard is actually mounted internal storage. If your files do not show up and errors are not thrown, be sure that you have storage permissions. I found this Adobe post with a useful code snippet describing how to check permissions and how to request them: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2250328

TL;DR

Ensure that storage permissions are enabled, and use /sdcard to store files in the internal storage when dealing with android versions 6 and up.